# Fetching data from mysql database

Tags: flutter

I am trying to connect my flutter app to mysql database and be able to fetch the data from the database and displays on the app

Below is the hardcoded code in the product model.

```
import 'package:grocery_shop_flutter/models/Product.dart';

class ProductsRepository{

  List<Product>  fetchAllProducts() {

    return [
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_noodles.png", "Biona Organic Spelt Noodles", 2.99, 250, 0),
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_italian.png", "Biona Organic Spelt Fusili Brown", 2.35, 500, 1),
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_spaghetti.png", "Biona Organic Whole Spelt Spaghetti", 2.35, 500, 2),
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_tagliatelle.png", "Biona Organic Spelt Spinach Artisan Tagliatelle", 1.99, 250, 3),
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_penne.png", "Biona Organic Whole Spelt Penne", 2.35, 500, 4),
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_tagliatelle.png", "Biona Organic Spelt Spinach Artisan Tagliatelle", 1.99, 250, 5),
      new Product("assets/images/spelt_fusilli.png", "Biona Organic Spelt Fusilli Tricolore", 1.99, 250, 6),
    ];
  }
}
```

I am a beginner in mobile development. I need examples, please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is sqlite plugin https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your app shouldn't make a direct connection to the database due to security issues. You should have a server application between client apps and database. You make requests to a server, server fetches data from database and responses back with the data. Basically you need a backend application to handle requests coming from your client apps. If you are new to this subject, you can start with Firebase.

If you want to directly connect Flutter app with a MySQL database for other reasons you can use the following plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you met by "You should have a server application between client apps and database" This might sound silly of me but do I have to make a different application that will communicate between my app and the database.

Comment: Correct, your mobile application will make a request to your server application. Let's say you want to retrieve users. Server application will make a query to your database and will return the results to your mobile application. By doing so you will have a trusted application to handle business logic, authorization etc. You can't trust client to handle these things. It would be a terrible idea to store your database credentials(username, password) in a client application since someone with the knowledge can extract that information.